# What's the meaning of "dai che lo sai già!"?

Tags: meaning

A child asked his father:

"Papà, la maestra ci ha parlato dell'antica Roma, ma non ho capito bene: chi la fondò?"

and his father replied:

"Dai che lo sai già! La fondarono Romolo e Remo, ma poi Romolo litigò con suo fratello e lo uccise".

What's the meaning of "Dai che lo sai già" here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***[Dai](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/D/dai_2.shtml)*** is a very common colloquial  interjection which means:

> ***come on, go on***:
>
> - dai, parla! come on, out with it!
>
> ***(che) lo sai già*** letterally means: ***(that) you  know that already***!

(Sansoni)

So the father is suggesting that the child actually knows who founded Rome. The child has just to think about it or he should know that already.

Comment: As an idiomatic translation into English I'd suggest "Come on, you know this!"